# How can I pull an array's data using a string variable as the name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I need to pull information for a specific argument (a string) from my JSON array, using the argument as the property name.

```js
let data = file.[argument];
console.log(data)
```

`argument` is the argument I'm using as the property name I'm pulling.
`file` is already defined as the file I'm pulling data *from*.

Comment: And your question is ... ? It's `file[argument]` btw, the dot is invalid syntax.

Comment: hi welcome to stack overflow, please state your goal and the problem. the [mre] might help us to give you better answer..

Comment: Welcome!  I would recommend reviewing [ask].  As stated, I am unclear on what exactly your question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

`let data = file.[argument];
console.log(data)`

you shoud do

```
 let data = file[argument];
console.log(data)
```

to access the property. For example, `file['name']` returns you the name of the object `file`